# using Alert Dialog like a toast, and without interrupting other activities for the user

Tags: android, notifications, dialog, alert, android-toast

I am new to android development. and I use in my application (alert dialog) in a builder to send notification massage to the user, just like the toast, but its clickable and can control the time of its appearance.

Now, my problem is that whenever the alert dialog is called, all video playback is paused and if the user is typing, the keyboard disappear, camera also suspended.

what I want is to call the alert dialog without interrupting the user UI or video playback and without acquiring the focus from other running applications.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

you can use **surface view** to get rid of your issues.

You can control the format of this surface and, if you like, its size; the SurfaceView takes care of placing the surface at the correct location on the screen

The surface is Z ordered so that it is behind the window holding its SurfaceView; the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its surface to be displayed. The view hierarchy will take care of correctly compositing with the Surface any siblings of the SurfaceView that would normally appear on top of it. This can be used to place overlays such as buttons on top of the Surface, though note however that it can have an impact on performance since a full alpha-blended composite will be performed each time the Surface changes.

The transparent region that makes the surface visible is based on the layout positions in the view hierarchy. If the post-layout transform properties are used to draw a sibling view on top of the SurfaceView, the view may not be properly composited with the surface.

[for detail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). Create a fragment each time you need a dialog like that, you can control lifetime, appearance, interactivity etc.

Comment: Can you give me a example on how the Fragments, will stop the alert dialog from stopping a video play back and do not affect the other activities running by the user please?

Comment: You can create lots of fragments running simultaneously within an activity. Think fragments like ordinary views with lifecycle events added, so you can pause them, resume, create and so on. See the tutorial on android website for more detail.